# Image viewing software

Tags: image-viewer

I need an image viewing software that can help me work with a slideshow of tons of pictures. By that I mean that I can jump forward and backwards by 1 picture, 10 pictures, 100 pictures …

Is there anything that can help me sort pictures in layers? By that I mean other than moving some amount of pictures backwards and forwards, I can also "move up and down" - If I'm on the 123th picture, then moving up switches me to the 123th image in the next folder; moving down goes to the previous folder.

I can adjust the view of the image. By that I mean temporary changes like increase in brightness, sharpen, focus on some spot, …

What image viewing software you know of that you can recommend?

Comment: For which operating system? May it cost something?

Comment: Are you asking if software exists or how to do to it? This is easily doable @Vepir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt a software that specific exist, jumping 10 or 100 slides and draggin them up and down.

IrfanView (for windows) can jump 5 slides when used in full screen mode, but can be used in windowed mode (To cover the full screen) and you can type the number of the image. But the order of that many images is using the name of the file, so they can not be "dragged". But your wierd concept of "layers" Can be done using folders.

It also can temporary change the brightness, sharpen, and if your image is bigger than the screen, (or you zoom in) you can drag the image arround, if that is what you mean by focus.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Adobe Lightroom.  It is impressively fast when showing photos and organizing them.  It also allows you to change your photos and then export them to a specified folder if different from the original.  It greatly increases my workflow.

You can even tether your camera to Lightroom for live shooting (Tether Tools).

As with any tool, learning shortcuts can make the tool even faster/easier to use.